# Folders with color Debian

Tags: debian, colors

Is there a package or app for Debian 8 that can change the color of folders?, or just tag them and allow them to be visually grouped by them (like the tag feature on MacOS).

Found [this](http://foldercolor.tuxfamily.org/) for ubuntu, but don't really want to install it without knowing compatibility or if there's a better option for debian.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using the default GNOME desktop, tags are built-in and can be used for searches: right-click on a file or folder, click on “Properties”, and you’ll see a “Tags” tab.

You can add emblems using the [`nautilus-emblems`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/nautilus-emblems) extension which is packaged in Debian.

Comment: But you cant change visually group the ones with the same tag

Comment: Indeed, that would be a useful feature.

Comment: That's what I want jaja. If there isn't a package that can do that then I could find a work around for what I want with emblems, so thank you!